# WHERE clause using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

The below code will select all the rows in a table, but I want to only select the id of the row that I pass into the method. I've tried it multiple ways and now starting fresh to see if I can get it work. Any help is appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
 [WebMethod]
public static string getProjectByID(int id)
{
    using (dbPSREntities4 myEntities = new dbPSREntities4())
    {
        var thisProject = myEntities.tbProjects.ToList();

        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var json = serializer.Serialize(thisProject);

        return json;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to use the [`Where`](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Restriction-Operators-b15d29ca/description#WhereSimple1) method to filter the data:

```
var thisProject = myEntities.tbProjects.Where(x => x.yourIdColumn == id).ToList();
```

Comment: SingleOrDefault is likely to be a better method to use here

Answer (score 3):

The where clause is fairly simple here. You just need to use a lambda expression to specify the condition you're matching on. If you're not familiar with them more info can be found here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx the basics are you have a variable name followed by `=>` on the right hand side you can do what you want with the variable and I find it easiest to think of it as working like a `foreach` where the variable name you declare is the iteration variable (an item in the list).

```
var thisProject = myEntities.tbProjects.Where(x => x.Id == id).ToList();
```

Comment: i think it may be clearer to the OP if you followed the format of his bit of code and made the parameter match the `id' one that he'd been referring to. just my thoughts...

Comment: @jimtollan yeah, that's a simple change. Didn't really look too closely at his code, just pulled that one line and added a where.

Comment: Thanks... it was simple but that's how new to LINQ I am. Thanks again!